# setTimeout() executing function immediately without delay

Tags: javascript, this, settimeout

I am trying to understand why this snippet of code logs the string `'Bob says hi'` immediately and does not wait the expected time.

```
var name = "Window";
var alice = {
  name: "Alice",
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log(this.name + " says hi");
  }
};
var bob = { name: "Bob" };

setTimeout(alice.sayHi.call(bob), 1000);
```

What is making the `setTimeout` function not execute after the wait argument?

The question has been marked as duplicate. Yet I don't see it being identical. This question is using call but the one referenced is not.

Comment: You're calling the method immediately and attempting to schedule the execution of the *result* of the function call.  What did you think `call(...)` did?

Comment: `setTimeout` wants a function reference, `call` calls the function immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) takes as the first parameter a function, `alice.sayHi.call(bob)` is not a function, it's `undefined` (it is the returned value of the function, not the actual function).

So you need to specify a callback instead, wrap your function inside another one like so:

```js
var name = "Window";
var alice = {
  name: "Alice",
  sayHi: function() {
    console.log(this.name + " says hi");
  }
};
var bob = { name: "Bob" };

setTimeout(() => {
  alice.sayHi.call(bob)
}, 1000);
```

In the above code (using the [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) I'm giving `setTimeout` the function `() => { alice.sayHi.call(bob) }`. After `1` second, the function will be executed i.e `alice.sayHi.call(bob)` will be called.